# Applescript to batch export with quicktime pro

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I need to export over 50 mp4 files to three different formats using Quicktime Pro. Currently I open the mp4, select the export options, choose filename to "save as" and start the process. I do this three times (one for each format) for each file.

Does anyone have Applescript scipt to automate such a process, or a tool that already exists to help?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can do this pretty easy with Automator in macOS.

Open Automator, then:

- New Workflow
- Click Files & Folders (left pane)
- Drag Ask for Finder Items onto the canvas (right pane)

  - Check "Allow Multiple Selection" next to the Type: Files drop down
- Click Movies (left pane)
- Drag Encode Media onto canvas below, choose Setting: Audio Only
- Run workflow, navigate to your folder and choose the video files.

Answer (score 1):

I explained how to do that in post #7 [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=9274).

Comment: The code generates an error on this line:

save export settings for QuickTime movie to file exportSettingsPath

I am running QT Pro version 7.6.6

Comment: John, I'm using 10.6 and "Quicktime Player 7" version 7.6.6 and it works fine. If you're using 10.6 then you have to change the application name to "Quicktime Player 7". If that's not your problem then did you change the script? If so then the line you mention expects the exportSettingsPath to be in text format, so if you changed the script maybe that's the problem. Try using... (exportSettingsPath as text) in the script.