# Keep original creation & modification timestamp while exporting with quicktime using applescript

Tags: quicktime

I realized that my GoPro videos are very large and that I can compress them by around 80% by loading the video in Quicktime and exporting the video in the 1080p format.

I found this automation for my problem: [applescript to batch export with quicktime pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170212/applescript-to-batch-export-with-quicktime-pro)

Unfortunately, I use to batch rename my video files according to the date & time taken (e.g. "2022-10-12, 15.24.13.mp4"). For the compressed video file, the creation & modification timestamp is not copied from the original file.

Any idea, how I can keep the original creation & modification timestamp for the compressed file? Or copy the creation & modification timestampe later from the original file into the compressed file? Maybe it helps that the files are named similarly except that the extension changes from "mp4" to "mov".

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: I just wanted to push my question. Any suggestions?